# How to connect with MySQL database using Java without localhost

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to MySQL database using Java using the code:

```
 try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd_Test","root", "root");

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

However, I want this connection to be made ​​without being over localhost. Is there any way for this?

I want the connection isn't localhost, because the objective is to create an installer application and that later can be accessed by other computers.

Thank you all for reply

Comment: You can, of course, connect to any database you want (and have access to). Just change your DSN.

Comment: What does "without being over localhost" mean? Are you asking how to change `localhost` to a different hostname?

Comment: Thanks for reply...Yes. I want to change localhost to a different hostname, because I need to run application in other computers.

Comment: So, umm, just change it?!

Comment: @user3320956 so change "localhost" to the host name of your mysql server..

Comment: Have you tried just changing "localhost" to "myotherhost"? What happens when you do? If it's an exception, please edit your post with the *full trace* of the exception.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the mysql database is behind a nat. You may need to port forward.

Comment: You need to always specify the host of the DB there. If you don't want to hard code this, have these in a properties file, so that you could change it without touching your code.

Comment: Or, you can see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql) solves your problem (whatever it might be).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure if this is enough to then run the application on other computers, but the only way to find out is by trying.

Comment: @user3320956 You didn't even try?....

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a real Question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clean this up a bit.

It sounds like your question is: **Can I connect to a database that is on another machine than my own?**

The answer is YES.

In your code snippet, simply replace 'localhost' with the IP address of the remote machine that is hosting the MYSQL database. In in interest of first testing this on your own, first replace 'localhost' with the 'loop-back' address of your own computer: 127.0.0.1 
Then test your existing code - you'll find that your application will still be able to query your local database because 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' are equivalent. Then when you're ready, simply replace the 127.0.0.1 IP address with the remote machine's.

Edit: As others have mentioned, the IP address may also instead be a public DNS (like www.google.com) or a machine name (although this is probably not your best option).

Comment: For a complete answer(as there's very little info in the question) you may want to consider the possibility that the sql database is behind a nat, in which case you'd have to port forward. Also if the machine with the database is assigned its IP through DHCP, this may not be reliable.

Comment: Sure - there are loads of additional factors here, but a general question can only receive an answer that is as specific as the question is itself.

Comment: I agree, but you've given a specific answer, to a very unspecific question

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I'll try all the possibilities that spoke and when you have a conclusion, put the answer here. And sorry if the question was not well formulated.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://TheHostName/bd_Test","root", "root");

} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: TheHostName can be an IP, ou something?

Comment: @user3320956 The HostName can be an IP, if it's under the same switch it can be a computer name(not actually sure the specifics here or when/how the computer name gets resolved), if it's over the internet it can be a domain name(assuming a registered DNS). There's many things a host name can be